# Calculations in a sequential manner?

Tags: math, textarea, calculator

I'm making a calculator in javascript. I have two modality for develop the operation. 
The first modality use the eval method. The second way that I have not completed, must execute the operation in sequential mode.

Example:

3-5x3/2

The code should not be executed before the multiplication, but must calculate the result in a sequential manner, ie:

3-5 = -2 * 3 = -6 / 2 = -3

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure how you are implementing it, but you can add brackets () around every operation. In that way it will be sequential.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean

Comment: Well, your example would be: (((3-5)*3)/2)

Comment: I understand, you want to add the parentheses? 
How can I do this via code? Can you show me an example, thanks.

Comment: Im not sure how to add this in code. I hoped you could do that yourself :P.